# Image gallery from mysql path and php with tree menu

Tags: php, mysql, database, image, gallery

i have this situation (mysql + php):

mysql:

```
    `| employee | visitday   | customername | picnumber | picpath   |
     ----------------------------------------------------------------
     |  agent 1 | 2014-02-16 |   customer   |    1      |c:\....jpg |
     |  agent 2 | 2014-01-11 |   customer   |    1      |c:\....jpg |`
```

in my site i have a tree menu like this: employee -> visitday -> customername, based on mysql

How can i do that when I click on customername to open a image gallery with customers pictures.

thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have some sort of file called customer.php

so the link to that customer in the menu could be something like: customer.php?name=customername

and then in customer.php use the following:

```
<?php
$customer = $_GET['name'];

if(isset($customer) && !empty($customer)) {
   $query = mysql_query("SELECT `id`, `customername`, `picpath` FROM `the table name` WHERE `customername` = '$customer'");


  echo '<table>
              <tr> <th>Foto</th> </tr><tr>';
   while( $associate = mysql_num_rows($query)) {
         echo '<td><img src="'.$associate['picpath'].'"></td>
              </tr><tr>';
   }
  echo '</tr>
     </table>';
} else {
     header('Location: index.php');
     exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: i have customer.php, but i keep geting unexpected '{' on third line and i can't figure it out

Comment: I missed a ) at the end of the if statement so if(isset($customer) && !empty($customer) { should be if(isset($customer) && !empty($customer)) {

Comment: one more question for you. for some reasons i get Undefined index: for the $customer. my menu is build like this `select * from visits v inner join visitdetails vd on v.employeedayid = vd.employeedayid group by v.employeename` and i echo with `$row['employeename']`; -> `$row['visitday']`; -> `$row['customername']` and i have included the file where the menu is stored

Comment: Looking at the code I guess the href should be something like: <a href="customer.php?name=<?php echo $row['customername']; ?>">Name</a>